# What are BPOs that are part of the Financial Services Cloud?

Tags: financial-services-cloud, bpo

In the Financial Services Cloud Administrator Guide [Data Model Overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_data_model_diagram.htm?search_text=bpo), the ERD has a legend of:

- Custom Object
- Standard Object
- BPO

with maybe half the objects shown marked as "BPO". In a trial org these objects appear in the Lightning "Object Manager" just as Standard Objects do i.e. with no namespace prefix and no `__c` suffix. They also appear in a new "Financial Services" section in the Classic Setup.

What is a "BPO"?

(My guess was “Business Process Object". Not too sure what enables them in an org; they're present in an FSC trial. Just a category of "Standard Objects"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BPOs means "Base Platform Object".

For what I have gathered over the years in the internets and conferences and videos and from a lot of other places about BPOs is

> WARNING: This is my opinion and deductions (based on my may years of
>   SF Experience. It's not information from salesforce  This information
>   is given as-is, any use of it is responsability of the subject using
>   it.

- It's an old denomination of Standard Object
- It was what it was (not extensible in like no triggers,...)
- Sometimes "Base platform" is used for all the base functionality needed for A platform to run (login, user management, Attachments, notes, security, sharing, history, ....)
- sometimes for packages is used as "the part of the package that salesforce manages" Meaning for example a CPQ package will use Opportunity and Quote objects, but they don't manage them, simply uses them.

Hoping this help.

Comment: Thanks Pablo - makes sense.